# Solving constraint optimization problem for different intervals using VariationalD

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus, functional

**I have been trying to solve for a constraint optimization problem (which eventually yields to a Laplace distribution).**

Consider the following equation **(1)**

\begin{equation*}
J=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p(x)\;log(p(x))\;dx\;-  \lambda_0 \biggl(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p(x)\;dx-1\biggl) -\lambda_1 \biggl(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x\;p(x)\;dx-m\biggl)-\lambda_2 \biggl(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \;\bigl(\sqrt {x^{2}}-m\bigl)p(x)\;dx-mad\biggl),
  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where, $m$ is the mean constraint, $mad$ is the mean absolute deviation. The above equation can then be solved as follows using the `variationalD` module from Mathematica (***for the functional derivatives***); (the following input can be directly pasted in mathematica to yield results)

```
In[1]:=<< VariationalMethods`
In[2]:=VariationalD[
 p[x] Log[p[x]] - Subscript[\[Lambda], 0] (p[x] - 1) - 
  Subscript[\[Lambda], 1] (x p[x] - m) - 
  Subscript[\[Lambda], 2] ((Sqrt[x^2] - m) p[x] - mad), p[x], x]
```

Which then gives an output which can be solved using other common methods.

**Q**. I am unable to do something similar for the following equation **(2)** which is similar to equation **(1)** except all its constituent functions do not have a uniform range;

\begin{equation*}
L=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)\;log(f(x))\;dx\;-  \lambda_0 \biggl(\int^{K}_{-\infty} f(x)\;dx-\epsilon\biggl) -\lambda_1 \biggl(\int^{K}_{-\infty} x\;f(x)\;dx-\epsilon\nu_{-}\biggl)-\lambda_2 \biggl(\int^{\infty}_{K} \;f(x)\;dx-(1-\epsilon)\nu_{+}\biggl)
  \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

*Please ignore the variables and take them at their face value.*

1. Could `VariationalD` be used to solve for **(2)**?
2. Can other Mathematica function be used to solve for **(2)**?

Thank you.

Comment: `VariationalMethods\`EulerEquations`?

Comment: @Αλέξανδρος-Ζεγγ No I haven't used `EulerEquations`, this is the `VariationalD` I am referring to [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/VariationalD.html)

Comment: Yes, I knew `VariationalD`. But in my opinion, the optimization of the functional $ J $ in Eq. (1) highly possible will be arriving at Euler-Lagrange equation(s) in the end, won't it?

Comment: The problem is one of basically maximum entropy, where p(x) is the probability, f(x) is the density function. 

In eq(1), one only need to `Solve` the output from `VariationalD` (which gives conditional expression), then create a function using If statement and including the conditional expression. 

Then simply solve the equation (1) as it is but use the new function. This gives a range for the mean absolute deviation (mad), which can then be manipulated automatically in mathematica. Apologies if I am not clear.